# Eclipse and PHPUnit: "The import PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase cannot be resolved"

Tags: eclipse, phpunit

I'm starting with PHPUnit, and it works fine so far. I just got one problem:
Eclipse (Oxygen.3) is telling me in this line:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
```

"The import PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase cannot be resolved"

I went to Window -> Preferences -> PHP -> Tools -> PHPUnit and added the path to my phpunit.phar. But this didn't help.

I went to Window -> Preferences -> PHP -> Source Paths -> Libraries and tried to import my phpunit.phar. But this results in an error "The selected file is not a valid user library data file".

Any other ideas how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same problem and this solution worked for me:

1. Going into **Project** > **Properties**
2. Under **PHP** > **Include Path**, pick the "**Libraries**" tab.
3. On "**Add External PHARs...**"  select the PHPUnit framework file on your system (phpunit.phar).

Comment: Thanks worked for me : `Eclipse Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
Build id: 20171218-0600`

Comment: `Eclipse for PHP Developers
Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200`  having so many problems with project creation wizard and phpunit

Comment: Thanks  a lot! It fixed reported problems after upgrading PHPTools in Eclipse for PHP Developers Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) Build id: 20170314-1500

Comment: Hi all why doesn't  usr/local/bin  phar file moved from mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit this command changes file extenstions .phar renamed

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was not able to **Add External PHARs...** as it ends up with error `Build path entry is invalid: org.ecl...nt/C:/xampp/php/phpunit-11.0.3.phar`.

What worked was to **Add External Source Folder** with the PHPUnit source code in `/xampp/php/pear/PHPUnit` folder.

Steps to create the external folder with PHPUnit:

- download the ZIP from [PHPUnit Github repository](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/archive/refs/heads/main.zip)
- Extract that .zip to folder into my PEAR/PHPUnit folder

  - folder will contain schema/ src/ etc.
- In Eclipse go to Project > Properties
- PHP > Source Paths > Include Path > Libraries tab
- [Add External Source Folder...] browse to the PHPUnit folder created earlier
- [Apply and Close]

After project refresh <kbd>F5</kbd> the PHPUnit methods were available.